# PHP read file (array) as array

Tags: php, arrays, file

How can I read a json array and add/merge a new element to it?

The content of my file `data.json` looks like this array:

```
[["2015-11-24 18:54:28",177],["2015-11-24 19:54:28",178]]
```

new element array example:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2015-11-24 20:54:28 [1] => 177 ) )
```

I used `explode()` and `file()` but it failed (delimiter for index 1..)..

has someone another idea or it is the right way to solve?

Comment: foreach first then use explode.

Comment: yes, the foreach stands..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need to import JSON content to your application as a string what can be done with `file_get_contents()`.

After that you have to decode--or "translate"--JSON format to PHP primitives via `json_decode()`. The result will be the expected array to be handled.

Then you may append a new item to that array using `[]` suffix eg. `$a[] = $b;`

These three steps are exemplified below.

```
// get raw json content
$json = file_get_contents('data.json');

// translate raw json to php array
$array = json_decode($json);

// insert a new item to the array
$array[] = array('2015-11-24 20:54:28', 177);
```

In order to update the original file you have to encode PHP primitives to JSON via `json_encode()` and can write the result to desired file via `file_put_contents()`.

```
// translate php array to raw json
$json = json_encode($array);

// update file
file_put_contents('data.json', $json);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$c = file_get_contents('data.json');
// <- add error handling here
$data = json_decode($c, true);
// <- add error handling here, see http://docs.php.net/function.libxml-get-errors
```

see http://docs.php.net/file_get_contents and http://docs.php.net/json_decode